# JSON::GeneratorError - App throws "only generation of JSON objects or arrays allowed" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I'm creating a ticket booking app for my sample project using Ruby on Rails 4.1. Three are three models - Events, Tickets and Bookings. Events have many tickets and bookings. Tickets have many bookings and they belong to events. Bookings belongs to events and tickets.

Here's the gemfile:

```
source 'http://code.stripe.com'
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.1.2'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'


# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'execjs'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'stripe'
gem 'tinymce-rails'
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'gmaps4rails'
gem 'heroku'
gem 'iconv'
gem 'multi_json', '1.10.1'
gem 'therubyracer'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'thin'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development
```

I use tinymce-rails gem to create a WYSIWYG editor in the new and edit pages. The gem requires to use <%= tinymce %> in all corresponding view files. The app was running fine and I was able to use the editor locally without any issues.

The new event page looks like:

```
<h2>Create an Event</h2>
<%= tinymce_assets %>
<%= form_for (@event) do |f| %>
  <% if @event.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@event.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
          this event from being saved:</h2>
        <ul>
        <% @event.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
  <% end %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :about %>
      <%= f.text_area :about, class: "tinymce" %>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <%= f.label :time_zone %>
      <%= f.time_zone_select :time_zone, nil, {}, {class: "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"} %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :start_date %>
      <%= f.datetime_select :start_date %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :end_date %>
      <%= f.datetime_select :end_date %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :location %>
      <%= f.text_field :location, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :contact_info %>
      <%= f.text_area :contact_info, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
      <%= f.hidden_field :latitude %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :longitude %>
      <%= f.submit "Create Event", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
    <%= tinymce %>
```

Yesterday I tried to deploy the app to Heroku. I followed this tutorial http://railsapps.github.io/rails-heroku-tutorial.html and precompiled the assets rake assets:precompile command.

Since then I'm unable to use the create and edit pages in the development and production environments. I get the JSON::GeneratorError - "only generation of JSON objects or arrays allowed" error and the <%= tinymce %> line at the bottom of the view file is highlighted. This happens in my local dev environment which was working fine before.

If I remove <%= tinymce %> from the pages, they load fine. I have tried adding rubyracer, execjs and mulit_json gems following earlier SE threads, but stll it doesn't work. How to get past this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official docs linked from your tutorial specify the following command to precompile: `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

Comment: Did you clear out the already precompiled assets before running it? I suspect one of your assets is loading twice, I've seen it from precompiled stuff in dev interfering, before.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear in the question. I'm now facing the same issue in my local dev environment as well. I want get the dev working fine before worrying about the production env.

Comment: Right. You compiled assets locally in the wrong environment, so they are now conflicting with your normal development assets. Remove the assets you compiled, and re-run the command with the environment set to production and it should sort itself out locally and in production.

Comment: So, this what I did now. I went into /public/assets and deleted the compiled assets. Then I ran the RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile command. Restarted the server, but, I get the same error in Dev.